# In the Android version of Waking Mars, how do I launch seed pods while flying?

Tags: android, waking-mars

With my Humble Bundle purchases, I now have both the PC and Android versions of *Waking Mars*. I started playing it on the computer, but changed my window manager and cannot continue there due to incompatibilities. So I installed the game on the phone.

In the computer version, I could launch seeds while in the air (using the right mouse button IIRC). On Android, the only way I have found to fly around is to tap a point in the direction I want to go to, and the only way I have found for launching seeds is to choose a seed from the menu, then tap in the direction I want the seed to fly. So far, I have not been able to launch a seed from flight, I always had to stand on firm ground. But from memory, I would say that the computer version allowed launching while I was floating in the air.

I am at the "vertical shaft" level right now, and I just can't find a way to get through it. Stuck at 45/70 biomass, I have seeds, but all the remaining fertile ground patches are on the vertical wall, and I have no place to stand in order to launch the seeds. I wonder if there is a control I overlooked which will allow me to launch the seeds from float, whether I oversaw some opportunity for growing more biomass, or whether I am supposed to be dexterous enough to launch the seed by selecting-and-tapping during a free fall.

Comment: seems that the only tag for controls is "keyboard" as a synonym for "keyboard-controls", maybe somebody will find a better tag.

Comment: The PC version definitely allowed you to toss seeds while using the jetpack. I'll take a look a little later and see if I can figure it out on Android (haven't played that version yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toss seeds in midair on the Android version of the game. Simply fly slightly above the location where you wish to toss the seed, release the finger guiding Liang, and quickly tap on the seed canister (you can also try tapping the canister with another finger, but in my experience on the tablet this doesn't always work).

The game will pause while you choose your seed, and Liang's jetpack will activate automatically after you choose your seed to slow his descent while you aim and throw. It takes a bit of practice, so try practising ahead in a safe area, but it is relatively easy to execute once you get the hang of it.